# msbuild.exe location on windows 8 with VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, msbuild, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm trying to set up a Jenkins CI server to deploy a .NET 4.5 app but I cant for the life of me find the msbuild exe on my windows 8 machine running visual studio 2012. Any ideas?

Comment: isn't it still in %windir%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.????

Comment: Yes... yes it is. I was adamant it was usually in Program Files/Microsoft.Net, oh dear, its been a long day. Submit comment as an answer if you want me to mark it. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make sure that you have installed the corresponding `.Net` framework.
You can find the **build.exe** by following this sample path

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.5\MSBuild.exe
```

Comment: The comment on my question solved it, but your also correct so might as well give somebody the points.

Comment: Technically this is wrong and you should use the registry to find it: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\${Version}\MSBuildToolsPath

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to locate MSBuild is to use the registry.

Here's a powershell implementation of finding a specific version of the .exe

```
$regKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\${Version}"
$itemProperty = Get-ItemProperty $RegKey -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($itemProperty -ne $null -and $itemProperty.MSBuildToolsPath -ne $null)
{
     $msBuildPath = Join-Path $itemProperty.MSBuildToolsPath -ChildPath "MsBuild.exe"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not like neither of the other answers. Because in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\` or registry you cannot find new msbuild version that was installed with visual studio or separately as build tools. The best way is to use `vswhere`
[find msbuild](https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere/wiki/Find-MSBuild)